# Does jQuery dispose events automatically on window unload

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks, event-handling, dispose

For example on a page I have

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#some-element').click(function()
    {
       // do something..
    });
});
```

Do I also need to add the unbind code - or will jQuery automatically do this for me?

```
$(window).unload(function()
{
    $('#some-element').unbind();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're asking about when the page refreshes (e.g. user clicks a link or something), then it doesn't matter since the page/client-side code no longer exist at that point.

So, I wouldn't worry about unbinding something in that scenario.

Comment: So no memory leaks you rekon?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do that.